# Возможно ли переделать файл с расширением .ino( Arduino) и запустить в среде Visual studio?

Tags: c++, arduino

То есть мне надо использовать библиотеку Arduino и запустить код в своей среде.

Comment: Добавить функцию main, в ней в начале одни раз вызвать функцию setup, потом в бесконечном цикле вызывать loop. Ну и реализовать те функции и объекты, которые вы в коде используете.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае так запросто не получится, ибо у авторов Arduino IDE чесались руки "усовершенствовать" язык С++ и они добавили в него ряд [сомнительных] свойств уровня препроцессора

1. Arduino IDE предлагает пользователю весьма спорную манеру упорядочения функций в `.ino` файле "от верхних к нижним", автоматически генерирует объявления для функций и помещает их в начало файла. Если ваш `.ino` файл написан в таком стиле, то объявления функций в начало файла вам придется добавлять вручную.
2. Arduino IDE неявно включает в `.ino` файлы некоторые заголовочные файлы, с объявлениями некоторых специфичных для Arduino IDE типов, вроде `boolean`. Если ваш `.ino` файл использует такие объявления, то вам придется добавлять их вручную. Сюда же можно отнести и более сложные нестандартные типы, вроде `String`.
3. Не совсем понятно что вы собрались делать с вызовами системного API Arduino.
4. Функцию `main` при необходимости придется написать самостоятельно.

Comment: Можно ли подключить библиотеку USB host shield 2.0 к Visual studio и будет ли драйвер работать с моим устройством(мышью). Я очень сомневаюсь.Мне нужно протестировать драйвер USB host shield( точнее написать его) а платы андруино у меня нет. Что можно еще попробовать?

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, скорее всего никак, только купить/где-то взять Arduino. Ну или эмулировать библиотеку USB host shield (по сути написать модуль, который будет делать вид что он эта библиотека).

Answer (score 0):

ino - это обычный файл С++, можно просто переименовать.

Все библиотеки Arduino написаны на стандартном C++, просто компилируются с отключенными исключениями.

Для большего понимания, советую найти файл `main.cpp` в папке Arduino и ознакомиться с его содержимым.